# Html tags inside Div/Class

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname

```
<Div class="abc">
 <Div class="def"><img src="www.xyz.com/abc.jpg">
  <Div Class="ghj"><a href....></a>
  </Div>
 </Div>
</Div>
```

i Just want to Print Tags+txt/htmls this:->

```
<Div class="def"><img src="www.xyz.com/abc.jpg">
  <Div Class="ghj"><a href....></a>
  </Div>
</Div>
```

i Tried `document.getelementsbyclass("abc")` but its not working any solution or help 
Thanks.!!

Comment: What is the question? And what has this got to do with PHP?

Comment: as i mention i want to print all html tags inside parent class "abc"

Answer (score 3):

First, it's not `getelementsbyclass` but `getElementsByClassName` and it returns a `NodeList` so, you need indexing and `innerHTML` is the property you're looking for.

```
console.log(document.getElementByClassName('abc')[0].innerHTML);
// [0] is to take the first element with class abc
```

Even better would be to use `querySelector` which takes CSS selector as its argument and returns a single element.

```
console.log(document.querSelector('abc').innerHTML);
```

Comment: I agree, except for the querySelector. Only use a querySelector when you have no other options. The reason? It's very slow in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is a language that is case sensitive. First of all `getElementsByClassName()` is a method that must be written in CammelCase. This method will return an array of DOM-nodes with that class. To get the html value of this element you use `innerHTML`.

**In short**

```
var html = document.getElementsByClassName('abc')[0].innerHTML;
```

This will get the HTML value of the first element with class 'abc';